# Android AlertDialog won't show until after bluetoothsocket.connect()

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` that is set to display before `bluetoothsocket.connect()`, which is a blocking method. However, the `AlertDialog` doesn't show until after the `bluetoothsocket.connect()` method finishes.

```
myalertdialog.show();
// Dialog is not shown.
mybluetoothsocket.connect();  // This blocks and takes a few seconds to run.
// Dialog is shown.
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bluetoothsocket.connect()` is blocking, which you said it is, you should put it out of the UI main thread. What you can do is put it inside an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Your `myalertdialog.show()` can be executed right before calling your `AsyncTask`. Then call `myalertdialog.hide()` in `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: You're right, the blocking code shouldn't run on the UI thread.  I moved it to an AsyncTask as you mentioned and it works perfectly now.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since bluetoothsocket.connect block UI calls its on separate thread

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();// This statement is to be called by the main thread

                myalertdialog.show();

                Thread t = new Thread(
                        new Runnable(){

                            public void run()
                            {

                                mybluetoothsocket.connect(); 
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        //ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }});
                t.start();
```